# angular 2 manipulate data in a service does not change that in second component

Tags: javascript, angular

I did a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GXAtBrEdPSxRhfUxllp9?p=info) involving this question.

I intend to pass data from one component to other components, via an angular service. These components do not necessarily have parent-child relationships.
The example flower data are originally stored in `DataService`.

Say, in component A, I have

```
changeName(tInput.value)
```

trying to manipulate data in `DataService`, with code as:

```
  changeName(name: string) {
    this.dataService.aFlower["name"] = name;
    console.log(`Name changed to ${ name }.`)
  }
```

Whereas in component B, a string variable

`objName: string = this.dataService.aFlower.name`

to get the data passed from `DataService`, and a property binding

`<h2 [innerHTML]="objName">h2 placeholder</h2>`

in template to display the data.

I also have a

`<h2 [innerHTML]="dataService.aFlower.name">h2 placeholder</h2>`

to directly fetch data from the service

The question is, when I input the new name and run `changeName("a new name")` in component A, the name does not change in component B .Both `h2` tags show original names.

Via debug tool I found that data fetched back from `DataService` were not altered.

Why is this happening and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the service provider at your module level, so it will be single to all child components, and remove declaration from each component. 
[Fixed plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5PwABiTqgtAMGvp7vzFH?p=preview)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppParent, AppChild ],
  bootstrap: [ AppParent ],
  providers: [DataService]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting *different instances of your service* in **`parent`** and **`child`**.

***You have to make sure that they both share a single instance of your service***.

So remove **`providers: [DataService]`** from both component's **`@Component`** decorator and add it to **`@NgModule`** decoarator as shown below,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppParent, AppChild ],
  bootstrap: [ AppParent ],

  providers: [DataService]             //<<<-----here

})
```